# How to do offline Maven builds?

Tags: maven

Occasionally - typically while I am traveling and/or have no internet connection or the connection is extremely slow or expensive - I would like be able to do Maven builds offline.

How do I do that and what do I have to do beforehand to preload all necessary information?

I already defined myself a local repository and added that to my settings.xml like so:

```
<settings ....>
    <localRepository>D:/m2Repository</localRepository>
    ...
</settings>
```

I also located the Maven options `-o` (offline) and `-nsu` (no snapshot updates) which according to their descriptions are supposed to allow exactly that, namely to do offline builds, but when I run my builds with these options added Maven nevertheless goes off and tries to download dependencies.

I specifically don't understand why Maven tries to download dependencies that definitely **are** in my local repo, e.g. the output of one of my offline attempts reads:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project <foobar>: Cannot access project-release (<URL to repo here>) in offline mode and the artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3 has not been downloaded from it before.
```

But when I double-check in my repo that listed artifact definitely **is** there! At exactly that path given (relative to the repo-root). So, why does Maven claim it has not been download, yet?

I also encountered the maven goals

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

and

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

Both run fine and show no error. But even after running these beforehand - when trying to build offline - I keep getting the same error message "Could not resolve dependencies ..."

I also fiddled with the `-llr` / `--legacy-local-repository` option but to no avail. :-(

What else is needed to convince Maven that the artifact is indeed there and no need to re-download so that it can build offline?

Comment: I had found that beforehand and have gone through all suggestions (except for those setting up a full-blown local repo - as cache so to speak). No solution worked, yet! My hope still is, that I can get away without having to setup a local Nexus or Artifactory but my confidence is dwindling...

Comment: You have to have running the full build at least once to get all the needed artifacts being downloaded afterwards you can work offline ...

Comment: Nope. Of course I have run the full build online (dozens of times, actually!) but I still can't go offline. This offline mode obviously doesn't work! At least not as described. :-(